# Transparency issue for images with alpha infront of GP in render?

Tags: rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine

I am trying to do a 2D animation and would like to have an image plane in front of the gpencil drawing.

A solution I found online was setting the plane's setting in material properties as Alpha clip, that helps in viewport rendering but not in normal render (ctrl + f12).

Comment: You should adjust your Question, the issue is not missing image in render, but transparency issue for images with alpha infront of GP in render. Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.